# Query failed: ERROR: error de sintaxis al final de la entrada LINE 1

Tags: php, postgresql

Estoy intentando resolver este error pero no logro dar con el, el error supuestamente es porque tengo un error de sintaxis, pero no logro darme cuenta en donde es.

El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php

include("conexion_bd.php");

$token = "eyJhbGciOiAiSFMyNTYiLCAidHlwIjoiSldTIn0=.DQp7DQogICAgInVzZXIiIDogIjEyMDI3NTc2MDAxNUBlcnAiLA0KICAgICJpc0NsaWVudCIgOiBmYWxzZSwNCiAgICAiaXNBZG1pbiIgOiBmYWxzZSwNCiAgICAiY2xpZW50IiA6IG51bGwsDQogICAgImlzUGFydG5lciIgOiBmYWxzZQ0KfQ==.J/h3dN+huAOgMq9cwyeMXRDgMZaejWKVvYypNVUWEFc=";

//parametros recibidos.-
$idfactura = $_REQUEST['idfactura']; 

//ACA DEBEMOS TRAER LOS DATOS DEL RECIBO GENERADO.
$sql_datos = pg_query("select * from actividad.facturas_originales where id = $idfactura");
$row_datos = pg_fetch_array($sql_datos);

$fechacomprobante = $row_datos['fecha_cfe'];
$formadepago = $row_datos['forma_pago'];
$tipomoneda = $row_datos['moneda_codigo_iso'];
$tipocfe=$row_datos['comprobante_codigo'];
$idfacturavinculada = $row_datos['idfacturavinculada'];
$cliente = $row_datos['cliente'];
$sql_vinculada = pg_query("select * from actividad.facturas_originales where id = $idfacturavinculada");
$row_vinculada = pg_fetch_array($sql_vinculada);
$serie_vinculada = $row_vinculada['serie_cfe'];
$tipo_vinculada = $row_vinculada['comprobante_codigo'];
$numero_vinculada = $row_vinculada['factura_cfe'];

$sql_datos2 = pg_query("select * from actividad.facturas_originales_items where idfactura = $idfactura");
$row_datos2 = pg_fetch_array($sql_datos2);
$nombreitem = $row_datos2['descripcion'];
$cantidad = $row_datos2['cantidad'];
$precio = $row_datos2['unitario'];

$metodo = "POST";
$ruta = "http://test.efactura.com.uy:60001/efactura/company/120275760015/cfe";
$datos = array( "tipoCFE" => $tipocfe,
    "fecha" => $fechacomprobante,
    "montosBrutos" => "1",
    "formaPago" => $formadepago,
    "receptor" => array(
        "documento" => "",
        "nombre" => "'.$cliente.'",
        "direccion" => "Ituzaingó 1460",
        "ciudad" => "PAYSANDU",
        "departamento" => "PAYSANDU",
        "pais" => "URUGUAY"
    ),
    "tipoMoneda" => $tipomoneda,
    //"tipoCambio" => $tipocambio,
    "detalles" => array(
        array(
            "indFact" => "6",
            "nomItem" => $nombreitem,
            "cantidad" => $cantidad,
            "precio" => $precio
        )
    ),
    "referencias" =>
    array(
        array(
            "tipo" => $tipo_vinculada,
            "serie" => $serie_vinculada,
            "numero" => $numero_vinculada
        )
    ),
    "adenda" => "Información comercial (opcional)",
    "IndCobranzaPropia" => "1",
    "conRepresentacionImpresa" => 1,
    "formatoRepresentacionImpresa"=>"application/pdf;template=a4"
);

$datos = json_encode($datos);

$respuesta = conexionRest($metodo, $ruta, $datos, $token);

$respuestaDecodificada = json_decode($respuesta, true);

$tipoCFE=$respuestaDecodificada['tipoCFE'];
$serieCFE=$respuestaDecodificada['serieCFE'];
$numeroCFE=$respuestaDecodificada['numeroCFE'];
Header("location:consultacfe.php?tipo_cfe=$tipoCFE&serie_cfe=$serieCFE&numero_cfe=$numeroCFE");
exit;
?>
```

El problema es que ese mismo error me está dando en las 3 consultas sql, y encima en el mismo lugar, es decir, cerca del where id=... y no me logro dar cuenta de cual es el error.

Adjunto captura de pantalla de dicho error, en donde se indica en que lineas está el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si me pueden dar una respuesta, lo agradezco debido a que hace algunos días que estoy con ese error. Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Puedes adjuntar el error completo para ver la línea en la que se lanza dicho error?

Comment: Lo de "cerca del where id=" es un poco difuso. Además, ¿tienes la definición de la tabla "facturas_originales"?

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta, y agregué captura de pantalla del error, a lo mejor se entiende un poco mejor ahora

Comment: A todo esto... ¿has comprobado el valor de `$idfactura`? ¿Es un id existente en la tabla de Facturas?

Comment: no aparece nada en idfactura

Comment: Necesitamos ver un `var_dump($_REQUEST);` puede que el problema sea que tus variables estén vacías. No debes nunca pasar a ejecutar una consulta sin antes verificar que los valores de las mismas no están vacíos.

Comment: Al hacer var_dump($_REQUEST); solo me devuelve array(0) { }

Comment: Pues eso, las variables están vacías. ¿Desde dónde y cómo estás mandando los datos a ese contexto? Muestra el eventual formulario lo que sea que envía tus datos.

Answer (score 0):

Con los datos que proporcionas, es difícil ver el problema.
Te aconsejo validar el resultado de $idfactura en la siguiente línea:

```
$idfactura = $_REQUEST['idfactura'];
```

Seguramente estés recibiendo un valor incorrecto para luego generar la consulta. Deberías enfocar tu atención en ese punto, por lo que veo.
Un pequeño truco es imprimir el valor de la variable por consola (o en su defecto la consulta completa) para que te ayude a encontrar el problema.